# Data structure to represent all combinations of available product?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures, combinatorics

Users can select from up to three dimensions of product data to choose the product they want. For example, for a pair of pants I might know:

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "soylent green"]
waists = ["28W", "30W", "omg random description", "32W"] // The values are not always numeric
lengths = ["26L", "27L", "28L", "29L"]
```

Represented in the DOM as:

```
<ul class="colors">
  <li><button name="red" value="red"/></li>
  <li><button name="blue" value="blue/></li>
  …
</ul>
<ul class="waists">
  <li><button name="28W" value="28W"/></li>
  <li><button name="30W" value="30W"/></li>
  …
</ul>
<!-- you get the picture -->
```

We also know that you can't get every combination of color, waist and length. When a partial configuration is chosen, we mark up the HTML to indicate what configurations are available given that choice. The data that gives me the available combinations must be delivered as JSON, and it must deliver the *sku* (string) of the product-configuration, but it can take any form that makes sense. What form should it take?

I've experimented with a 3-dimensional array where defined values are skus and `null` or undefined values are unavailable configurations:

```
[ // Arrays of colors
  [ // Arrays of waists
    [ // Array of lengths
      "sku-1", "sku-2", "sku-3", null, "sku-4"
    ], [
      "sku-abc", null, "sku-def"
    ]
  ], [
    [ … ], …
  ] …
]
```

This is the most compact, but leads to slow, unreadable code. When the customer hovers over a waist size button, I have to find the indices of that value in the waists array and eliminate all the other dimensions of waist, then get the indices of `null` values and mark them as unavailable. There are a lot of `for` loops here.

Another approach I tried was with a nested object. Unavailable combinations are simply undefined:

```
{
  "red": {
    "28W": {
      "28L": "sku-123",
      "30L": "sku-456"
…
}}}
```

But if the user hovers over, say, `"28L"`, I have to iterate through all the outer objects to find those that *don't* have a property of `28L`.

If I just needed to know which configurations were unavailable, I could make a list of those configurations, but since I also need the `sku`, it's become complex. What data structure do you makes the best tradeoffs between size and speed (and readable code, if possible), keeping in mind it will be run client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure speed is an issue ? Is your catalog very very large (tens of thousands of items) ?

Why not use a flat structure ?

```
{
"sku-123" : ["purple", "28W", "32L"],
"sku-998" : ["orange", "44W", "10L"]
}
```

Or with keys

```
{
"sku-123" : {color: "purple", w: "28W", l: "32L"},
"sku-998" : {color: "orange", w: "44W", l: "10L"}
}
```

Sure it's not the fastest, you'll have to traverse all products to filter them out. But it will make the code more readable (you can use predicates), and easier to adapt to other situations (e.g. adding new fields).

Unless you have already verified that speed is an issue, I wouldn't dismiss this easy way to do it.

Comment: I estimate the largest product sets may have not more than 5000 configurations. So maybe you're right and I'm overthinking it, but I'd like to see what anyone else has to say.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here.  1. Efficient propagation of the information to the browser 2. Efficient searching of that information.  I would suggest getting that info to the browser as efficiently as possible while keeping it in JSON so at least the data should parsed natively and then indexing the crap out of it, making whatever dictionaries necessary to efficiently perform the searches.  I might start out with three dictionaries, each for the categories of choice, and then for the values use an array for those skus that match the key (with the sku's other two attributes).  As to which dictionary to use if the user has made multiple choices, well that's up to you, but it might make sense to use the dictionary with the least number of values per key as a default and only use the other two dictionaries when the user has only made one choice.

You have lots of options, I'm only giving you a few.  And, furthermore, remember, these are optimizations, the more you make, the harder it might be to change for a new behavior.